# MySQL Select Random from All but not double time

Tags: php, mysql

i want to show Random Item with Select by `WHERE code = $Code`

But if he finds like 10 Items, i want to show only 1 by 1. All 10 must show in a Row, Random Order with a 5 seconds timer. The Problem is, i dont will show the same Item again and again. If the 10 Items are done, he must look again to database and start again

I already tried to do it with putting all in array but my skills are low :(

Thats my try...

```
$result = $db->query( 'SELECT * FROM ads WHERE zipcode = "'.$zipcode.'";');
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $data[] = $row;
}

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $random = rand(0, $count);
    $count -= 1;

    $result[] = $data[$random];
    echo json_encode($data);
    unset($data[$random]);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: i added my try to question :)

Comment: so you want to randomly show 1 item of 10 but prevent from showing it twice in a row right?